# cross field validation with angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, custom-validators

I am trying to create a validator that checks that the beam (width of a boat) is not greater than the length.  In the component:

```
this.vesselForm = this.fb.group({
  beam: [null, [
    Validators.required,
    BeamValidators.beamCannotBeGreaterThanLength,
  ]],
  length: [null, Validators.required],
});
```

In the file beam.validators.ts:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class BeamValidators {

    static beamCannotBeGreaterThanLength(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
      const hullLength = control.parent.controls['length'].value;
      // const hullLength = 48;
      console.log(hullLength);
      if ((control.value >= hullLength)) {
          return { beamCannotBeGreaterThanLength: true };
      } else {
          return null;
      }
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to access the length from the validator.  The code compiles past intellisense but errors out in the browser with the console error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
    at BeamValidators.beamCannotBeGreaterThanLength (beam.validators.ts:6)
```

The rest of the program works fine using the test line // const hullLength = 48;

Answer (score 2):

To implement cross validation, you must lift the validation to the `FormGroup` level.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ValidatorFn, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

const beamValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
  const beam = fg.get('beam').value;
  const length = fg.get('length').value;

  return beam < length ? null : { beamError: true };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input [formControl]="form.get('beam')" type="number" />
    <input [formControl]="form.get('length')" type="number" />
  </form>

  {{ form.valid }}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      beam: [null, [
        Validators.required,
      ]],
      length: [null, Validators.required],
    }, { validator: beamValidator});
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qst5jp)

I'm trying to get this type of validation included in the official documentation. If you think it would be a good fit, please consider upvoting this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23182).